# Actuator endpoints returns "circuitBreakers":{"status":"UNKNOWN"} despite management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled: true

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator, resilience4j

I have a Spring Boot 2.6.0-M1 project with Jubilee (But issue can be reproduced since 2.4).
In my project, I am using Actuator, Spring cloud Kubernetes, and Resilience4J (not Spring Cloud Circuit breaker)

Very happy about this combination. Resilience4J is working fine, the circuit breaker goes into open states etc. Kubernetes detect the config maps, etc... Very happy.

However, on a actuator health endpoint, I am seeing this :

`"circuitBreakers":{"status":"UNKNOWN"}`

And checked my configuration, `management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled: true`

How do I get the correct status, and not this "UNKNOWN" please?

Thank you

Comment: can you set the following property in your application.yml? It will show you more details when you hit the `/health` which might make it easier to understand why it is returning "UNKNOWN". 

`management.endpoint.health.show-details: "ALWAYS"`

Comment: Great idea! Let me try right away

Comment: Still "UNKNOWN", even with management.endpoint.health.show-details: "ALWAYS" :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use actuator along with resilience 4j please use the configuration mentioned below.

Make sure to add your service name and it works perfectly.

```
resilience4j.retry.instances.customerService.max-attempts: 3
resilience4j.retry.instances.customerService.wait-duration: 5s
management.endpoint.health.show-details: "ALWAYS"        
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled: false 
management.health.ratelimiters.enabled: true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.registerHealthIndicator: true
```

Answer (score 2):

Circuit breaker showing status unknown because you are missing one of the required properties in application.properties file.

You should add below property:

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.{App Name}.registerHealthIndicator = true
```

Also check below properties:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details: "ALWAYS"        
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled: false 
management.health.ratelimiters.enabled: true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.registerHealthIndicator: true
```

Answer (score 0):

UNKNOW is also a kind of state of CircuitBreaker, which means half-open state. A closed CircuitBreaker state is mapped to UP, an open state to DOWN and a half-open state to UNKNOWN. You can see explain [here](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#health-endpoint)